# why can not find exactly one wifi while all other are visible in `available wifi`?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mobile-hotspot

I am trying to use wifi(**HOME_WIFI**) created using mobile hotspot(**xiaomi**). My OS is windows 10, at first i successfully connected and used smoothly. Then suddenly can not find the **HOME_WIFI** anymore. That same wifi(**HOME_WIFI**) is visible to all other mobile and laptop. 
Also my laptop can find all other available wifi except **HOME_WIFI**.

I tried the following solutions

- Turn off firewall to check if firewall is blocking the wifi
- Manage known network -> HOME_WIFI  -> Forget
- Restart everything
- Recreate mobile hotspot
- Tried to change frequency from mobile but it only supports 2.4 GHz

Comment: What OS is the laptop? Windows? First turn the hotspot off, on the laptop search "wifi" in the search bar, open Wi-fi Settings, go to Manage known networks, click on the "HOME_WIFI" and click "Forget". Then start the hotspot back up and search for the wireless name/SSID. If you have no luck there, make your way to the configuration settings for the wifi device in the laptop, go to Advanced, see if there are "Preferred Band" or just "Band" settings and make sure they're not set on 5g first, 5g only, etc. I wouldn't think that would cause your issue but I've seen stranger things. Also, check

Comment: Yes im using windows 10. ```Forget network``` didn't work for me. Can you please be more elaborate where to find ```configuration settings```? Nothing opened up in windows search bar when typed "configuration settings".

Comment: type Control Panel in search and open it, in the upper right corner make sure "View By" is set to small icons, open "Network and Sharing Center", on the left side click "Change Adapter Settings", it'll show your network adapters, you'll see your wifi adapter and maybe some others (i.e. an ethernet adapter depending on your laptop model), right click on your wifi adapter, click Properties, when the window appears click the "Configure" button, it'll open a new configuration window for the wifi device, then go to the Advanced tab, check any settings pertaining to "band" or "preferred band"

Comment: Check the Wifi channel. Channels higher than 11 are not allowed in some countries and devices that are not configured sometimes assume the are in the USA (max channel=11) and ignore those higher channels even if they are allowed in the country you are in.

Comment: @JJC8008 No such options "band" or "preferred band".

Comment: @Robert how do i do this? could not find such settings in mobile, please elaborate thanks

Comment: If you have a second Android device (that runs Android up to v9) you can use [Wifi Analyzer app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer) to check which channel is used (and what other channels are used around you).

Comment: @Robert Yes ```WIFI ANALYZER``` says ```HOME_WIFI``` uses channel 13. Can i change the channel without rooting my phone? What do i do now?

Comment: @mahfuj asif, where do you live? I'm curious because ch-13 is restricted in every phone I have ever seen, and disabled here in the u.s because of FCC regulations.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Bangladesh, using xiamo redmi 6. In my windows 10 region is selected Bangladesh and language is English US. Dunno why im getting such restriction in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a Wifi is not visible on one or two devices of a large pool this usually means that the Wifi is running on a channel that is not available world wide (for 2.4GHz channels 12-14 are not available in every country of the world).

If you have a second Android device running max Android 9 you can use [Wifi Analyzer app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer) and check which channel is used.

If you have verified that a channel higher than 11 is used there two options:

1. Configure the hotspot to use a lower channel (1-11). For Android before 10 there is usually the possibility to configure the channel in the advanced options of the mobile hotspot. By default the channel should be set to **auto**. See also [this question on the hotspot channel](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8365)
2. You can check the device(s) that do not see the Wifi with a high channel if they have been correctly set-up for your country (assuming you are in a country using the channel used by the mobile hotspot is allowed). For smartphones this usually means that a SIM card of your country is inserted and at least connected once after reboot. Linux and Windows devices can also be configured for a specific country: See for example [this topic for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944845/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to solve the problem without rooting my phone, so it might take some time. So far i don't see any way to change channel without rooting, so trying to solve by working with windows 10.